# Does the return type save space or time

Tags: c, types, casting, return, cpu-registers

Does the return type matter when returning from a function?

This is kind of a 2-part question.
I believe an 8-bit operation would be the same as a 32-bit operation.
I believe an 8-bit value is operated on in a 32-bit register, so it will be promoted to a 32-bit value. Then it would be casted back down to an 8-bit value.

```
unsigned char SomeFunc()   <- Quickest and less memory.
unsigned short SomeFunc()
unsigned long SomeFunc()
```

"All operations should be performed on the smallest variable wherever possible, this saves both time and space" True or False?

On a 32 bit operating system, I don't believe it would matter, since the return register is 32 bits anyways, whether it be a variable or an address.
So it would neither save time, nor space.

I do understand that there might be a need to return a char/byte, if that's all your dealing with, but you could still return a long and cast it.
I think your still casting either way whether before or after you leave the function. I almost think it is easier and faster to deal with 32 bit values than 16 or 8 bit values.

Second part.
In the following function, I don't believe it would make it any quicker or save any more space if I were to return a unsigned short instead.

```
unsigned long SomeFunc(unsigned char a, unsigned char b);
{
  unsigned long c = a + b;
  return c;
}
```

or

```
unsigned long SomeFunc(unsigned char a);
{
  //This will be promoted to a 32-bit value anyways.
  return a & 0x1;
}
```

The following function would somehow be quicker and take up less memory?

```
unsigned char SomeFunc(unsigned char a);
{
  //This will be promoted to a 32-bit value anyways.
  return a & 0x1;
}
```

Comment: If you really want to know what's going on, look at the generated assembly of each example.

Comment: This question on Stack Exchange Software Enginering may be of interest: [Is it a good practice to use smaller data types for variables to save memory?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144792/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-smaller-data-types-for-variables-to-save-memory)

Comment: "All operations should be performed on the smallest variable wherever possible, this saves both time and space" --> False.  Processors/compilers are designed for optimal speed/performance based on various criteria, usually the "native" type(s).

Comment: Thanks Weather Vane. I found the statement which makes sense "Now it becomes more efficient, code-wise, to use ints for most variables instead of chars or shorts. But once again, any type of array or structure must be considered whether smaller data types are warranted. Unlike compilers for larger systems, it is more likely variables in a structure will be packed on an embedded system. I take care to always try to put all 32-bit variables first, then 16-bit, then 8-bit to avoid any "holes"."

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Trust your optimizer. Don't fight the type system.

---

Yes, you should use the smallest type.

Depending on your compiler they may compile differently and your compiler might have good reason to do that. If you lie to your compiler about the types you're messing with its ability to optimize your code.

And because you don't know how the return value will be used.

Not all memory is a single variable. Consider arrays and structs. They are allocated in large blocks beyond the 32 or 64 bit native sizes. If you return larger type than necessary you're forcing that an array or struct storing it to use more memory. For example, if you return an `int` where you should be returning a `char` and I have to store those values in array that array will be 4 to 8 times larger.

> *I do understand that there might be a need to return a char/byte, if that's all your dealing with, but you could still return a long and cast it. I think your still casting either way whether before or after you leave the function. I almost think it is easier and faster to deal with 32 bit values than 16 or 8 bit values.*

The return value tells people reading the code what type to use to store the return value. If you habitually use larger types than necessary and just need to know which ones you can cast to smaller types, that's hidden information only you know. And if it's in your head you're going to forget.

Gratuitous casting defeats the safety of the type system. Type checks let you know if you're putting data of the wrong type or size into the wrong place. Casting tells the compiler "I know this looks wrong, but trust me I know what I'm doing". This should be done only when necessary. If you're gratuitously casting you lose this help from the compiler. If you make a mistake the compiler cannot help you.

Finally, it will befuddle anyone reading your code. They'll scratch their heads and wonder why you're always shoving longs into shorts and ints into chars. They'll never know which are ok and which are mistakes.

---

As to `unsigned long` vs `unsigned char`, compiling your two functions with `clang -O3 -S` and diffing the assembly reveals a slight difference:

```
-   movq    %rdi, %rax
+   movl    %edi, %eax
```

The `unsigned char` implementation will use a 32-bit register while `unsigned long` will use a 64-bit register. Does this matter? Dunno, probably not. Definitely not enough to defeat the type system.